# Custom Security filter chain is not used

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-security

Fixed it by adding @Import(SecurityConfig::class) to my EventControllerTest.

I have the following controller in a Spring Boot 3 application using Kotlin:

```
data class EventRequest(
    val name: String
)

data class EventResponse(
    val name: String
)

@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/v1/events")
class EventController {

    @PostMapping
    @ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.CREATED)
    fun addEvent(@RequestBody event: EventRequest): EventResponse {
        return EventResponse(name = event.name)
    }
}
```

And the following security config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity(debug = true)
class SecurityConfig {

    @Bean
    @Throws(Exception::class)
    fun customSecurityFilterChain(http: HttpSecurity): SecurityFilterChain {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .formLogin().disable()
            .authorizeHttpRequests().requestMatchers("/api/**").permitAll()
        return http.build()
    }
}
```

And the following test:

```
@WebMvcTest
class EventControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var mockMvc: MockMvc

    @Autowired
    private lateinit var objectMapper: ObjectMapper

    @Test
    fun `add event successfully`() {
        val event = EventRequest(name = "My event")
        val body = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(event)

        this.mockMvc
            .perform(
                post("/api/v1/events")

                    .content(body)
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON))
            .andExpect(status().isCreated)
    }
}
```

The test fails with this message: `Status expected:<201> but was:<403>`

And with this in the log:

```
2023-04-07T22:27:23.343+02:00  INFO 94918 --- [    Test worker] d.n.h.controller.EventControllerTest     : Starting EventControllerTest using Java 17.0.6 with PID 94918 (started by ricn in /Users/ricn/src/spring/happy-events)
2023-04-07T22:27:23.344+02:00  INFO 94918 --- [    Test worker] d.n.h.controller.EventControllerTest     : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
2023-04-07T22:27:23.779+02:00 TRACE 94918 --- [    Test worker] eGlobalAuthenticationAutowiredConfigurer : Eagerly initializing {org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration$WebSecurityEnablerConfiguration=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.servlet.SpringBootWebSecurityConfiguration$WebSecurityEnablerConfiguration@5af64ce0}
2023-04-07T22:27:23.782+02:00  WARN 94918 --- [    Test worker] .s.s.UserDetailsServiceAutoConfiguration : 

Using generated security password: cad9d91c-b1b9-451a-a8e6-967f744395a9

This generated password is for development use only. Your security configuration must be updated before running your application in production.

2023-04-07T22:27:23.840+02:00  INFO 94918 --- [    Test worker] o.s.s.web.DefaultSecurityFilterChain     : Will secure any request with [org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@245253d8, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@12417468, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@2bb41f5c, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@4f281aaf, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@7f73ce28, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@61191222, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@27dc627a, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter@5921b93c, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter@459003a0, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@359066bc, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@7da635c0, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@79a13920, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@d325518, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@4d93f75b, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@77724cbe]
2023-04-07T22:27:23.869+02:00  INFO 94918 --- [    Test worker] o.s.b.t.m.w.SpringBootMockServletContext : Initializing Spring TestDispatcherServlet ''
2023-04-07T22:27:23.869+02:00  INFO 94918 --- [    Test worker] o.s.t.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet  : Initializing Servlet ''
2023-04-07T22:27:23.870+02:00  INFO 94918 --- [    Test worker] o.s.t.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet  : Completed initialization in 1 ms
2023-04-07T22:27:23.883+02:00  INFO 94918 --- [    Test worker] d.n.h.controller.EventControllerTest     : Started EventControllerTest in 0.673 seconds (process running for 1.152)
2023-04-07T22:27:24.091+02:00 TRACE 94918 --- [    Test worker] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Trying to match request against DefaultSecurityFilterChain [RequestMatcher=any request, Filters=[org.springframework.security.web.session.DisableEncodeUrlFilter@245253d8, org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter@12417468, org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextHolderFilter@2bb41f5c, org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter@4f281aaf, org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter@7f73ce28, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter@61191222, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter@27dc627a, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter@5921b93c, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLogoutPageGeneratingFilter@459003a0, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter@359066bc, org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter@7da635c0, org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter@79a13920, org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter@d325518, org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter@4d93f75b, org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.AuthorizationFilter@77724cbe]] (1/1)
2023-04-07T22:27:24.091+02:00 DEBUG 94918 --- [    Test worker] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Securing POST /api/v1/events
2023-04-07T22:27:24.092+02:00 TRACE 94918 --- [    Test worker] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking DisableEncodeUrlFilter (1/15)
2023-04-07T22:27:24.092+02:00 TRACE 94918 --- [    Test worker] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter (2/15)
2023-04-07T22:27:24.093+02:00 TRACE 94918 --- [    Test worker] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking SecurityContextHolderFilter (3/15)
2023-04-07T22:27:24.093+02:00 TRACE 94918 --- [    Test worker] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking HeaderWriterFilter (4/15)
2023-04-07T22:27:24.094+02:00 TRACE 94918 --- [    Test worker] o.s.security.web.FilterChainProxy        : Invoking CsrfFilter (5/15)
2023-04-07T22:27:24.095+02:00 DEBUG 94918 --- [    Test worker] o.s.security.web.csrf.CsrfFilter         : Invalid CSRF token found for http://localhost/api/v1/events
2023-04-07T22:27:24.096+02:00 DEBUG 94918 --- [    Test worker] o.s.s.w.access.AccessDeniedHandlerImpl   : Responding with 403 status code
2023-04-07T22:27:24.096+02:00 TRACE 94918 --- [    Test worker] o.s.s.w.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter  : Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match request to [Is Secure]

MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = POST
      Request URI = /api/v1/events
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = [Content-Type:"application/json;charset=UTF-8", Content-Length:"19"]
             Body = {"name":"My event"}
    Session Attrs = {org.springframework.security.web.csrf.HttpSessionCsrfTokenRepository.CSRF_TOKEN=org.springframework.security.web.csrf.DefaultCsrfToken@49c83262}

Handler:
             Type = null

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 403
    Error message = Forbidden
          Headers = [X-Content-Type-Options:"nosniff", X-XSS-Protection:"0", Cache-Control:"no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate", Pragma:"no-cache", Expires:"0", X-Frame-Options:"DENY"]
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []
```

To me it looks like my custom security filter chain is not loaded because `Invalid CSRF token found for http://localhost/api/v1/events`is logged but I've disabled it.

I have also tried to debug the application and set a breakpoint in the customSecurityFilterChain method but application never stops there.

The same thing happens if I run the application and perform a POST request manually.

Any ideas?

Update with folder structure:

```
tree
.
├── main
│   ├── kotlin
│   │   └── dev
│   │       └── nystrom
│   │           └── happyevents
│   │               ├── HappyEventsApplication.kt
│   │               ├── config
│   │               │   └── SecurityConfig.kt
│   │               └── controllers
│   │                   └── EventController.kt
│   └── resources
│       ├── application.properties
│       ├── db
│       │   └── changelog
│       │       └── db.changelog-master.yaml
│       ├── static
│       └── templates
└── test
    └── kotlin
        └── dev
            └── nystrom
                └── happyevents
                    ├── HappyEventsApplicationTests.kt
                    └── controllers
                        └── EventControllerTest.kt
```

build.gradle.kts:

```
import org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.tasks.KotlinCompile

plugins {
    id("org.springframework.boot") version "3.0.5"
    id("io.spring.dependency-management") version "1.1.0"
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.8.10"
    kotlin("plugin.spring") version "1.8.10"
}

group = "dev.nystrom"
version = "0.0.1-SNAPSHOT"
java.sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_17

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    implementation("com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-kotlin")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-reflect")
    implementation("org.liquibase:liquibase-core")
    implementation("org.springframework.session:spring-session-core")
    implementation("org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity6")
    implementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    developmentOnly("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
    runtimeOnly("org.postgresql:postgresql")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test")
    testImplementation("org.springframework.security:spring-security-test")
}

tasks.withType<KotlinCompile> {
    kotlinOptions {
        freeCompilerArgs = listOf("-Xjsr305=strict")
        jvmTarget = "17"
    }
}

tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

HappyEventsApplication.kt:

```
package dev.nystrom.happyevents

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.boot.runApplication

@SpringBootApplication
class HappyEventsApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<HappyEventsApplication>(*args)
}
```

Comment: Where is your main function? I dont see it in your tree

Comment: @Toerktumlare It's located in the HappyEventsApplication.kt file. Will add the content for that file as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to add `@Import(SecurityConfig::class)` to my EventControllerTest class.